# XCode Instruments Automation missing

Tags: xcode, instruments

I want to do UI automation tests using Xcodes Instruments. But it seems like "Automation" is missing. How can I add this?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Xcode 7.3 if you want to use the Automation instrument.

Apple removed the Automation instrument in Xcode 8. Use Xcode's user interface testing to test your app's user interface in Xcode 8.

Comment: Is there a way to use Javascript as it used to be possible with Automation ? I'm trying to simulate frequent GPS location updates, which used to be done with Automation and some JS.

Comment: @GrahamSlick I haven't used Xcode's user interface testing much so I can't tell you if it supports Javascript.

Comment: Ok thanks for your answer. Did you ever have to simulate gps updates ? if yes, how did you proceed ?

Comment: @GrahamSlick I haven't simulated GPS updates. That sounds like a good topic for a new question here.